# Check ISO is valid or not

Tags: iso

Is there any C# way to check an ISO file is valid or not i.e. valid Iso format or any other check possible or not.
The scenario is like, if any text file(or any other format file) is renamed to ISO and given it for further processing. I want to check weather this ISO file is a valid ISO file or not? Is there any way exist programmatically like to check any property of the file or file header or any other things

Thanks for any reply in advance

Answer (score 4):

To quote the wiki gods:

> There is no standard definition for ISO image files. ISO disc images
>   are uncompressed and do not use a particular container format; they
>   are a sector-by-sector copy of the data on an optical disc, stored
>   inside a binary file. ISO images are expected to contain the binary
>   image of an optical media file system (usually ISO 9660 and its
>   extensions or UDF), including the data in its files in binary format,
>   copied exactly as they were stored on the disc. The data inside the
>   ISO image will be structured according to the file system that was
>   used on the optical disc from which it was created.

[reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to *detect* whether a file is an ISO file or not, and not so much check the file, to see if it's valid (e.g. incomplete, corrupted, ...) ?

There's no easy way to do that and there certainly is not a C# function (that I know of) that can do this.

The best way to approach this is to guess the amount of bytes per block stored in the ISO.
Guess, or simply try all possible situations one by one, unless you have an associated CUE file that actually stores this information.  PS.  If the ISO is accompanied by a same-name .CUE file then you can be 99.99% sure that it's an ISO file anyway.

Sizes would be 2048 (user data) or 2352 (raw or audio) bytes per block.  Other sizes are possible as well !!!! I just mentioned the two most common ones.  In case of 2352 bytes per block the user data starts at an offset in this block.  Usually 16 or 24 depending on the Mode.

Next I would try to detect the CD/DVD file-systems.  Assume that the image starts at sector 0 (although you could for safety implement a scan that assumes -150 to 16 for instance).

You'll need to look into specifics of ISO9660 and UDF for that.  Sectors 16, 256 etc. will be interesting sectors to check !!

Bottom line, it's not an easy task to do and you will need to familiarize yourself with optical disc layouts and optical disc file-systems (ISO9660, UDF but possibly also HFS and even FAT on BD).

If you're digging into this I strongly suggest to get IsoBuster ([www.isobuster.com](http://www.isobuster.com)) to help you see what the size per block is, what file systems there are, to inspect the different key blocks etc.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above (and especially [@peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650419/peter)'s answer): I recently made a very simple Python tool for the detection of truncated/incomplete ISO images. Definitely *not* validation (which as [@Jake1164](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373334/jake1164) correctly points out is impossible), but possibly useful for some scenarios nevertheless. It also supports ISO images that contain Apple (HFS) partitions. For more details see the following blog post:

[Detecting broken ISO images: introducing Isolyzer](http://openpreservation.org/blog/2017/01/13/detecting-broken-iso-images-introducing-isolyzer/)

And the software's Github repo is here:

[Isolyzer](https://github.com/KBNLresearch/verifyISOSize)

Answer (score 0):

You may run `md5sum` command to check the integrity of an image

For example, here's a list of ISO: http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/5.4/isos/x86_64/

You may run:

```
md5sum CentOS-5.4-x86_64-LiveCD.iso
```

The output is supposed to be the same as `1805b320aba665db3e8b1fe5bd5a14cc`, which you may find from here:

http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/5.4/isos/x86_64/md5sum.txt